# Can I use the adjective "illusionary" to describe a person's apparent trait?

Tags: word-usage

Can I use the adjective "illusionary" to describe a person's trait of character that is not real but is highly suggested by their appearance?:

> It’s funny, but she always has this look on her face as if she were
>   bored and not willing to talk to you. That is, however, quite
>   **illusionary** – you just need to ask her only one small question to know
>   that that’s not true.

Comment: I believe the word you're looking for is **illusory**, not 'illusionary.'  Here is Merriam-Webster's definition of "illusory": https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/illusory

Answer (score 2):

The word **illusionary** isn't dead wrong by any means, but you're not hitting the bullseye.  The sense that she is bored would be a *misimpression* not an illusion.

But that's just in my judgment. Another reader might consider **illusionary** the *mot juste*.

Comment: What adjective would you personally use?

Comment: I wouldn't use an adjective.

Comment: So what construction would you use?

Comment: Do you think I could use the word "treacherous" or would that be even more awkward?

Comment: Treachery seems to come out of nowhere.

Comment: :( :( :(  I see..

Comment: You say **That**, using the demonstrative pronoun to refer to "this look on her face as if she were bored and not willing to talk to you".  The person looking at her is reaching that conclusion. Whether that's deceit on her part (she wants to look bored and unapproachable even though she is not) or fear on her part, or simply an error of judgment on the part of the onlooker is the question.

Comment: I see. So, probably I need something like "the assumption that she is unapproachable, however, would be quite erroneous"

Comment: Well, that's moving in the direction of clarity, but you've upped the register quite a bit.  :)

Comment: @brilliant *That is, however, quite* ***unrepresentative*** *(of her actual feelings).*

Comment: @JasonBassford - Can I drop "actual feelings" and just say _That is, however, unrepresentative of her_?

Comment: @brilliant Yes, but it would be a bit strange since you've used ***always*** *has this look*. Without that, this one time could be considered a departure from her *normal* look of interest and willingness to talk—and just *of her* would work. But if she always has a negative appearance, then it actually is representative of her outward behaviour.So, emphasizing actual feelings (despite habitual appearance) makes more sense. It's best to specify the actual thing that's different from its representation.

Comment: @JasonBassford -  I see. Thank you. You can re-post it as an answer.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Feel free to incorporate this into your own answer. I had only meant to provide commentary, not an answer of my own. :)

Comment: Is she wearing a mask, so to speak?